# Density slicing on raster with multiple bands

Tags: qgis, raster, hyperspectral-sensor

I want to style a 2 band raster file by density slicing in QGIS.

I know I can select one band and display the ranges using 'singleband pseudocolour' or 'palleted/unique values', but the data I want to display is kept in two bands. Is it possible to display the data in two bands using this method?